# How to Update fields using where conditions Current user = Key ( User ID) firestore and flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I'm using flutter and firebase so I have firestore  I have on collocation name Institutes and in document has names of Institutes  and my Fields I have profile data ….no I need update some fields by where conditions  where currant user = Key User id in the fields*

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaeWX.png)

```
onPressed: ()async {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final user = await auth.currentUser();
    final iduser = user.uid;
    final emailuser = user.email;
    final snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection("Institute")
        .document(_Institute_name.text).get();
    if (snapshot.exists) {
        print(this name is existd);
    } else {
        await  DataBaseService(email: emailuser,
        uid: iduser,
        Document: _Institute_name.text)
            .CreateCollectionInofwithImage(
        _Institute_name.text, Institute_address.text,
        int.parse(Institute_phone.text), _image).then((isdone) {
            setState(() {
                Institute_address.clear();
                Institute_phone.clear();
                _Institute_name.clear();
                _image = null;
            });
        });    
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain your question better

Comment: I need when user make save has profile save on just one document ..its working good and it's save but  when click one more time to click button its save another document  I don't do   I need in when click one more time do update fields where user id = current user id …. Has my idea reached or not?

Comment: Excuse me if I find a mistake in my English

Comment: Ok so i kinda get what you want please post the code you have tried and read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I post my code above  I've checked the document if  exists or not  if not exists  create data here before create data  I need check  if  currant user has data or not  if not create new document if  has data before make update to the old data

Comment: did this help you

Answer (score 0):

Okay try this

```
onPressed: ()async {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final user = await auth.currentUser();
    final iduser = user.uid;
    final emailuser = user.email;
     QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('Institute')
      .where('user id', isEqualTo: iduser)//I think this is your field name from the 
//picture it looks like theres a space in it
      .getDocuments();
  if (snapshot != null) {
    Map<String,dynamic> document = snapshot.documents[0].data;
    //Then you would reference this by document['fieldName']

    } else {
        await  DataBaseService(email: emailuser,
        uid: iduser,
        Document: _Institute_name.text)
            .CreateCollectionInofwithImage(
        _Institute_name.text, Institute_address.text,
        int.parse(Institute_phone.text), _image).then((isdone) {
            setState(() {
                Institute_address.clear();
                Institute_phone.clear();
                _Institute_name.clear();
                _image = null;
            });
        });    
    }
}
```